# How to get ID from a relationship table, Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-7, eloquent-relationship

I have 4 table : Users, CompanyRegister, VoucherDetails, Addvoucher.
So the Authenticate Users Id will be submit as user_id in companyRegister table,and then companyRegister ID will be submit as company_id in Voucherdetails table, and lastly voucherDetails Id will be submit in addVoucher table as voucher_ID. I am new to using eloquent and also laravel, I cant understand why I cant get the id from voucherdetails and submit in addvoucher but I can get id from companyregister and submit in company_id in voucherdetails. I'm using the same method to get id but not work, I hope can get solution and explanation here,Thank you in advance!!

My users model

```
public function companyregisters()
    {
         return $this->hasOne('App\companyregisters');
    }

public function voucherdetails()
{
     return $this->hasMany('App\voucherdetails');
}

 public function addvoucher()
{
     return $this->hasMany('App\addvoucher');
}

public function roles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\role');
}

public function hasAnyRoles($roles)
{
    if($this->roles()->whereIn('name', $roles)->first()){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

  public function hasRole($role)
{
    if($this->roles()->where('name', $role)->first()){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

my companyregister model

```
public function User(){
         return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

public function voucherdetails()
{
     return $this->hasMany('App\voucherdetails');
}
```

my voucherdetails model

```
  public function User(){
     return $this->belongsTo('User');
}


public function companyregisters(){
     return $this->belongsTo('App\companyregisters');
}

    public function addvoucher()
{
     return $this->hasOne('App\addvoucher');
}
```

my addvoucher model

```
    public function User(){
     return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}

public function voucherdetails(){
     return $this->belongsTo('App\voucherdetails');
}
```

my voucherdetailsController

```
         public function store(Request $request){
    
    $voucherdetail = new voucherdetails();

    $voucherdetail->title = $request->input('title');
    $voucherdetail->description = $request->input('description');
    $voucherdetail->user_id = Auth::user()->id;

    $id = Auth::user()->id;
    $user      = User::find($id);
    $company   = $user->companyregisters;
    $companyId = $company->id;

    $voucherdetail->company_id = $companyId;

    $voucherdetail->save();
    
    return redirect()->to('addvoucher');
        
    }
```

my addvoucherController

```
        public function store(Request $request){

    $addvoucher = new addvoucher();

    $addvoucher->voucherTitle = $request->input('voucherTitle');
    $addvoucher->voucherCode = $request->input('voucherCode');
    $addvoucher->user_id = Auth::user()->id;

//Here(the voucherdetails id cant get to submit in voucher_id)

    $id = Auth::user()->id;
    $user      = User::find($id);
    $voucher   = $user->voucherdetails;
    $voucherID = $voucher->id;

    $addvoucher->voucher_id = $voucherID;

    $addvoucher->save();
    
    return redirect()->to('displayVouchers');

}
```

Comment: which part specifically is not working, could you maybe add a comment like "// this line here, I dont get the correct value" or similar?

Comment: I have edited Sir

Comment: I see, adding an answer now

Comment: alright sir, I got this error also sir when using that method "Property [id] does not exist on this collection instance."

Comment: Indeed, see the answer below for why that happens :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code works because companyregisters is a [hasOne](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one) relationship for which the docs say:

> Once the relationship is defined, we may retrieve the related record
> using Eloquent's dynamic properties.

```
public function companyregisters()
{
   return $this->hasOne('App\companyregisters');
}

$company   = $user->companyregisters; // ie this returns the single related record 
$companyId = $company->id;            // and it has an `id` property, all good here
```

However, this code fails because `voucherdetails` is a [hasMany](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many) relationship for which the docs say:

> Once the relationship has been defined, we can access the "collection"
> of comments by accessing the comments property.

[More info on collections](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-collections#introduction)

```
public function voucherdetails()
{
     return $this->hasMany('App\voucherdetails');
}


$voucher   = $user->voucherdetails; // ie this returns a "collection" of related records
$voucherID = $voucher->id;          // this "collection" does NOT have an id property, but each record IN the collection does.
```

In summary, either your relationship is defined incorrectly (hasMany vs hasOne) or, you'll need to loop over the related records to get the id from each.

Comment: sir but my voucherdetails model was hasOne not hasMany

Comment: The above is copied from your posted code. You might have _meant_ for it to be `hasOne` but you made it a `hasMany`, if thats the case, fix that and you should be good to go :)

Comment: Thank You So much for your explanation sir its solved my problem, :)

Comment: It was my mistake instead of hasOne I put hasMany thats y :(

Comment: @balamurugana Awesome, happy to help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222521/discussion-between-bala-murugana-and-wesley-smith).